# Intellij cannot find module in project

Tags: go, intellij-idea

I have a Go project. While setting the run config of the project. I am getting Module "doesn't exist in project". Run kind is selected as package. Post cloning intellij asked for building the project, I did that so here is the picture of error  I am getting.

[image]

Update: Module option is blank, there is nothing to select.

Comment: You need to select a module in `Module` field, so IDE will know the settings of which module it should use for building (SDK, build tags, etc.)

Comment: there is nothing to select in module.

Comment: It means you don't have modules with Go support enabled. Check it in the `Settings | Languages & Support | Go | GOROOT` or open any Go file in the editor, IDE will suggest you set GOROOT and/or enable Go support for a particular module.